# how to filter rows on SQLFORM.smartgrid wrt to a certain field value in the table

Tags: web2py

I have a table in my db.py, and want to put an edit/delete/view option to it using smartgrid. I require to filter the records and display only those records which have been uploaded by the currently logged in user. I have a field in my table called uploaded_by which holds the username of the person who uploaded a certain project.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to show a single table in the grid, you should use `grid` rather than `smartgrid`, in which case, the first argument can be a query rather than a table:

```
grid = SQLFORM.grid(db.mytable.uploaded_by == some_id, ...)
```

If for some reason you do need `smartgrid`, you can use the `constraints` parameter to specify filters for particular tables:

```
grid = SQLFORM.smartgrid(db.mytable,
                         constraints={'mytable': db.mytable.uploaded_by == some_id}, ...)
```